# Hololens 2 UWP C# App: Issues with Front-Facing Camera at Higher Resolutions (2272x1278) and NV12

Tags: c#, uwp, hololens, nv12-nv21

I am developing a UWP C# application for the Hololens2. I am trying to access the front facing camera using MediaCapture and MediaFrameReader.
So far everything works fine as long as I keep the resolution at 896x504. As soon as I try to change the resolution to 2272x1278, the image I'm getting is corrupted.

As I am only interested in the gray values, I just copy the luminance values from the software bitmap. With the NV12 format, these should be right at the beginning of the buffer. When I visualize the copied data, I get an image like the one below (here the camera is looking at a white wall). The image shows strange diagonal stripes and nothing is visible.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jHmz.jpg)

I also tried the YUV2 format and it works fine, but copying the pixel data takes more time.

Am I missing something?

[EDIT] I put a demo application on [Github](https://github.com/RichardFieb/Hololens2_CameraCapture) to showcase the problem.

Here are some code snipet I am using to accessing the pixel data:

- init MediaCapture:

```cs
string deviceId = await GetDeviceId();
var mediaInitSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = deviceId };
IReadOnlyList<MediaCaptureVideoProfile> profiles = MediaCapture.FindAllVideoProfiles(deviceId);

var match = (from profile in profiles
    from desc in profile.SupportedRecordMediaDescription
    where desc.Subtype == "NV12" && desc.Width == 2272 && desc.Height == 1278 && Math.Abs(desc.FrameRate - 30) < Tolerance
    select new { profile, desc}).FirstOrDefault();

if (match != null)
{
    mediaInitSettings.VideoProfile = match.profile;
    mediaInitSettings.RecordMediaDescription = match.desc;
    mediaInitSettings.SharingMode = MediaCaptureSharingMode.ExclusiveControl;
    mediaInitSettings.MemoryPreference = MediaCaptureMemoryPreference.Cpu;
}
else
{
    mediaInitSettings.VideoProfile = profiles[0];
}

_mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(mediaInitSettings);
```

- init FrameReader:

```cs
const MediaStreamType mediaStreamType = MediaStreamType.VideoRecord;
CameraParameters parameters = new CameraParameters(_cameraProfile);

MediaFrameSource source = _mediaCapture.FrameSources.Values.Single(frameSource => frameSource.Info.MediaStreamType == mediaStreamType);
var preferredFormat = source.SupportedFormats.Where(format => 
                format.VideoFormat.Height == parameters.CameraResolutionHeight
                &&
                format.VideoFormat.Width == parameters.CameraResolutionWidth
                &&
                Math.Round(format.FrameRate.Numerator / format.FrameRate.Denominator - parameters.FrameRate) < Tolerance
                &&
                format.Subtype == "NV12");

var selectedFormat = preferredFormat.FirstOrDefault();
await source.SetFormatAsync(selectedFormat);

_frameReader = await _mediaCapture.CreateFrameReaderAsync(source, selectedFormat.Subtype);
_frameReader.FrameArrived += OnFrameArrived;
```

- copy the pixel data:

```cs
private async void OnFrameArrived(MediaFrameReader sender, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args)
{
    if (sender == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sender));
    if (args == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(args));

    using (MediaFrameReference mediaFrameReference = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame())
    {
        if (mediaFrameReference == null) return;
        var videoMediaFrame = mediaFrameReference.VideoMediaFrame;
        var softwareBitmap = videoMediaFrame?.SoftwareBitmap;
        
        if (softwareBitmap != null)
        {
            var width = softwareBitmap.PixelWidth;
            var height = softwareBitmap.PixelHeight;

            // copy only luminance plane of NV12
            byte[] rawPixelData = new byte[width * height];
            using (var buffer = softwareBitmap.LockBuffer(BitmapBufferAccessMode.Read))
            using (var reference = buffer.CreateReference())
                unsafe
                {
                    byte* pixelData;
                    uint capacity;
                    ((IMemoryBufferByteAccess)reference).GetBuffer(out pixelData, out capacity);
                    Marshal.Copy((IntPtr)pixelData, rawPixelData, 0, rawPixelData.Length);
                }
            
            FrameArrived?.Invoke(this, new FrameArrivedEventArgs(rawPixelData, width, height));
            softwareBitmap.Dispose();
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to reproduce this issue. You mentioned that it can work in the YUV2 format, but I don't seem to find this format. Could you tell us which profile it is? Any more details?

Comment: Hi, I did not implement the YUV2 part in the demo application. I can add this the next day and update the repository and let you know.

Comment: @ZuochengWang-MSFT I updated the repository with Yuy2 code.